# Lagged and leading variable dummy variables for events study - Stata

Tags: stata, dummy-variable

In the context of a difference-in-differences analysis, I would like to perform an **events study** to check for anticipatory and adjustment effects. To do so, I need to create dummy variables for the years

```
t-3, t-2, t-1, t+1, t+2, t+3
```

Below is an example of my data structure:

| Year | ID | Presence |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2000 | 1 | 0 |
| 2001 | 1 | 0 |
| 2002 | 1 | 0 |
| 2003 | 1 | 0 |
| 2004 | 1 | 0 |
| 2005 | 1 | 1 |
| 2006 | 1 | 1 |
| 2007 | 1 | 1 |
| 2008 | 1 | 1 |
| 2009 | 1 | 1 |
| 2010 | 1 | 1 |
| 2000 | 2 | 0 |
| 2001 | 2 | 0 |
| 2002 | 2 | 0 |
| 2003 | 2 | 0 |
| 2004 | 2 | 0 |
| 2005 | 2 | 1 |
| 2006 | 2 | 1 |
| 2007 | 2 | 1 |
| 2008 | 2 | 0 |
| 2009 | 2 | 0 |
| 2010 | 2 | 1 |
| ... | ... | ... |

How do I create the dummy variables `t-3 , t-2, etc.` in Stata?

Comment: What in your data defines the date of the event(s)?

Comment: @NickCox I'm not sure if I get your question. Let me try to give an example in the context of an event study (please correct me if I get this wrong): The code should create e.g. a variable "Presence_t-1" that should already take the value 1 for ID 1 in year 2004, "Presence_t-2" should take the value 1 for ID 1 starting in year 2003 and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the extra detail, but if I understand correctly I don't see anything non-standard in  what you want. Use time series operators to get the variables you want.

Comment: @NickCox: Thank you. Just to be crystal clear, my ultimate goal is to create an analysis such as the one on page 26 https://economics.mit.edu/files/11616
Could you please give me a hint on how to get started with the time series operators?

Comment: `help time series operators`

Comment: @NickCox: Thanks. Just to be sure, that would get me to create an analysis such as the one I shared in the link above? Appreciate your feedback!

Comment: Sorry, I am not going to study a lengthy document to answer your question. Questions here should be self-contained to the extent possible.